# Three-way pivot Table Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I'm struggling to connect three models in my Laravel app. The models are Bottle, Label and Spirit. I want to get all the labels based on bottle_id and spirit_id so I created a pivot table to store the relationships between Bottle-Label-Spirit. Please see below my current setup.

**DB**

```
+---------+--------+---------+-------------------------+
| bottles | labels | spirits | bottle_label_spirit     |
+---------+--------+---------+-------------------------+
| id      | id     | id      | id                      |
| name    | name   | name    | bottle_id               |
|         |        |         | label_id                |
|         |        |         | spirit_id               |
|         |        |         | created_at              |
|         |        |         | updated_at              |
+---------+--------+---------+-------------------------+
```

Where `bottle_label_spirit` is my pivot table

**BOTTLE CLASS**

```
class Bottle extends Model
{
    public function labels() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Label::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function spirits() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Spirit::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**LABEL CLASS**

```
class Label extends Model
{
    public function bottles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Bottle::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function spirits() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Spirit::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**SPIRIT CLASS**

```
class Spirit extends Model
{

    public function labels() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Label::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function bottles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Bottle::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**QUESTIONS**

So my questions are:

- Is this the right approach to handle this `manyToMany` relationships?
- If yes, how do i get all the labels where bottle_id = 1 and spirit_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a 4th table for this, you can accomplish all of this using [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). This will allow you to query distant relationships.